# Virtual buttons not appearing on emulated Android 4.2 system

Tags: emulation, android-sdk-tools, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have created an Android 4.2 AVD. For the need of my current project, the main screen orientation is landscape. The software keys option is selected.
The mode is set to xhdpi, like a Galaxy Nexus phone.

As I start the emulator, I see a black stripe on the right where the buttons should appear, but it remains black. Thus, there is no way to trigger a Back action since the emulated physical keys are disabled.

The problem can be fixed by configuring the emulator in portrait mode then rotate it once started; the buttons appear as expected. This causes problems since the window is automatically scaled down to fit on my monitor; I did not find any shortcut to restore 1:1 scaling at runtime, after the rotation is done. This is important since I would like to see pixel-perfect results.

I am using SDK version 21 and platform-tools version 16.0.2, as updated yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself... this is a workaround that allows getting 1:1 scale and the software buttons working.

- Leave the AVD (Galaxy Nexus or cloned from it) on portrait mode.
- Run the emulator from the command line, using the `-scale 1` option; this is the magic that forces 1:1 pixel perfect ratio even if the window does not fit in screen at startup. By default, automatic downsizing happens to fit the monitor.
- Rotate the display using Ctrl+F11 or Ctrl+F12 to get landscape mode.